# ipa file without UDID

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to create an .ipa file without adding UDID's of the devices it needs to be tested on.

I work at a small company and it is hard for me to get the device information of the client's devices.

I have looked into the Apple Enterprise developer program and that will not work because you are not allowed to distribute the apps outside of your company.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the new beta program made available by apple with the test flight and ios8 integration. You only need the email of the beta testers.

> External Testers
>   Once you’re ready, you can invite up to 1,000 users who are not part of your development organization to beta test an app that you intend for public release on the App Store. Apps made available to external testers require a Beta App Review and must comply with the full App Store Review Guidelines before testing can begin. A review is required for new versions of your app that contain significant changes. Up to 10 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seems like only iOS 8 apps can be tested with the above method which might be a problem. (we use all the way upto iOS 5)
Also, the apps might have to go to the Beta app review which might take a while. 

We are trying to find a simple solution to distribute our apps, which might not be possible.

Comment: Without jailbreak I think you cannot do that